# Why can't value constructors take type variables WITHOUT parameterizing the type?

Tags: haskell

As a beginner, it's not obvious to me why this is not allowed:

```
data Pair = Pair a b
```

That is, why do `Pair 5 "foo"` and `Pair 'C' []` HAVE to produce different types? Why is it not allowed for them both to create values of type `Pair`?

I'm learning from "Learn you a", RWH, and the Haskell WikiBook, but have not been able to find the kind of precise, wonky language describing parametrized types that I'm looking for.

Comment: What would be the type of projections then? Haskell has static type system, what you ask requires runtime type inspection.

Comment: You can define that type with the `ExistentialQuantification` extension (`data Pair = forall a b. Pair a b`), but it remains useless, as explained by Vitus and Tikhon.

Comment: Vitus - By projection, do you mean a function that returns one of the component values?

Comment: Daniel - thanks... I'll check those things out in about a year :)

Comment: @spartan_dev: Indeed. For pair (tuple of size 2), those are `fst` and `snd`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fundamentally, the issue is that you would have no information about the contents of `Pair`. If all you know is that it contains a value of *any* type, the only real function you could use on it would be `id`, which is pretty useless!

The problem is that, since each value could be *anything*, you have no guarantees about them at all. So you couldn't even use `==`: what if the value was a function? You can't compare functions for equality!

Imagine writing a function acting on your hypothetical `Pair` type:

```
fn (Pair a b) = ...
```

What other functions could you use on `a` and `b`?

Anything with any sort of concrete type (e.g. `Int -> Int` or something) wouldn't work because you can't tell if `a` is an `Int`. More complicated types like `Num n => n -> n` wouldn't work because you don't even know if `a` is a number. The only functions that *would* work are ones with types like `t1 -> t1` or `t1 -> t2`. However, the only reasonable function of the first type is `id` and there is no *reasonable* function of the second type at all.

Now, you could just say "I'm going to try this function, if the type doesn't work, throw an error." But this would then be dynamic typing and would basically be throwing away the type system entirely. This sounds horrible, but it might make sense sometimes, so you can use `Data.Dynamic` to accomplish something like that. However, you shouldn't worry about it as a beginner and chance are you will never need to use it--I haven't, so far. I'm just including it for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 4):

With the existential types language extension you can define such a type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Pair = forall a b. Pair a b

a, b :: Pair                                
a = Pair 1 2
b = Pair "abc" 'x'
```

Here both `a` and `b` have the same type.

Usually this isn't done this way because to do anything useful with a `Pair` you'd need to know what it contains, and the definition of `Pair` removes all that information.

So you can create such values if you really want, but it's hard to find anything useful to do with them.